# How to read CDF file with python on mac?

Tags: python, macos-mojave

I have installed spacepy using the following command (MacOS Mojave):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/spacepy/spacepy.git
```

But I keep getting this error while trying to `from spacepy import pycdf`:

> Exception: Cannot load CDF C library; checked . Try 'os.environ["CDF_LIB"] = library_directory' before import.

I have tried following [the directions from their website](https://pythonhosted.org/SpacePy/install_mac.html#spacepy), but it seems like those directions are a bit outdated.

Comment: `pip install spacepy --user` their latest version is available on pypi, according to the website

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried doing that, but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
import os
os.environ["CDF_LIB"] = "~/CDF/lib" # Give the path of the cdf library
# e.g. in this case the library is in your home directory.
```

Before doing:

```
from spacepy import pycdf
```

Source of the error can be found on [this](https://pythonhosted.org/SpacePy/_modules/spacepy/pycdf.html) SpacePy website.

The cdf library is available [here](https://pythonhosted.org/SpacePy/pycdf.html).

Basically, you need to set up the CDF_LIB (if pycdf has a trouble finding it) before importing the module. You can read the documentation [here](https://pythonhosted.org/SpacePy/pycdf.html).

Comment: I tried that and still had the same error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-728dd0e9ba6a> in <module>()
      1 os.environ["CDF_LIB"] = '/Users/rafaelmesquita/PerlCDF37_1/blib/lib'
----> 2 from spacepy import pycdf
      3 import os

Comment: Did you set the correct path? `os.environ["CDF_LIB"] = "yourpath"`